# Memoir 3.7e: treating bibliography like a section, not a chapter

Tags: biblatex, memoir

**Update**: as pointed out in [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe)'s comment below, the 'culprit' is not `memoir` but `biblatex`. The change was introduced in v. 3.0 of `biblatex`, and as a result the bibliography is printed as a chapter unless `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]` is specified.

---

Using the `memoir` class (v. 3.7c), with the `article` option, the bibliography is formatted like a section.

For example:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\makechapterstyle{mydefault}{
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setsecheadstyle{\raggedright\scshape}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\raggedright\itshape}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\raggedright\itshape}
}

\chapterstyle{mydefault}


\begin{document}

\section{First section}

This paper really is very good: \cite{Bli74}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

yields the following:

[image]

Using `memoir` v 3.7e, however, yields the following instead:

[image]

From looking at the `.aux` file, the following line suggests that the references section is now being treated as a chapter:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{References}{1}}
```

The corresponding bit in the `.aux` file using 3.7c has this instead:

```
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{References}{1}}
```

Is this behavior intended? I couldn't find anything in the newest version of the manual to suggest that it is.

I should add that the switch to the newer version of `memoir` happened when I upgraded to `texlive` 2015. I haven't tried to see what happens if I use the older version of `memoir` using `texlive` 2015, so I've been switching  to `texlive` 2014 in order to use the older version of `memoir`. But my guess is that the problem is not with the newer `texlive` distribution, but with the newer version of `memoir`.

In any case, I would like to be able to force memoir to treat the bibliography as a section, at least when using the `article` option. I tried explicitly redefining `\bibsection`, as suggested on p. 300 of the manual for v 3.7e, but that doesn't seem to make a difference::

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\makechapterstyle{mydefault}{
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setsecheadstyle{\raggedright\scshape}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\raggedright\itshape}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\raggedright\itshape}
}

\chapterstyle{mydefault}



\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\bibsection}{%
   \section{\bibname}
   \prebibhook}

\section{First section}

This paper is very good: \cite{Bli74}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it isn't Memoir that changed but `biblatex`. [Correct bibheading levels for memoir (article)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/85f1e6e18ddbd08ea800f1157ac27c60c7f5a252) was committed 2014-11-13 following [pull request #284](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/284) to fix [issue #283](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/283). This code was first included in `biblatex` 3.0 (released 2015-04-20, AFAIK didn't make it to TeX Live 2014), in previous versions of `biblatex` Memoir's `article` option would use `\section*` and not `\chapter*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `biblatex` package disables or redefines many features of `memoir`, making `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{...}` useless.

The `biblatex` manual states in section 3.12.2: Usage with the memoir class:

> When using Biblatex with the memoir class, most class facilities for
>   adapting the bibliography have no effect. Use the corresponding
>   facilities of this package instead (§§ 3.6.2, 3.6.8, 3.6.9). Instead
>   of redefining memoir’s \bibsection, use the heading option of
>   \printbibliography and \defbibheading (§§ 3.6.2 and 3.6.8). Instead of
>   \prebibhook and \postbibhook, use the prenote and postnote options of
>   \printbibliography and \defbibnote (§§ 3.6.2 and
>   3.6.9). All default headings are adapted at load-time such that they blend well with the default layout of this class.

Redefine `\defbibheading` etc. to change to `\section` or `\section*` instead!

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}



\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\makechapterstyle{mydefault}{
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setsecheadstyle{\raggedright\scshape}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\raggedright\itshape}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\raggedright\itshape}
}

\chapterstyle{mydefault}


\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
\section*{#1}%
\markboth{#1}{#1}}


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}

This paper is very good: \cite{Bli74}.


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Two questions, though. First, doing this changes the name of the bibliography to "Bibliography" as opposed to "References". (I can change it back, but I wonder why this happened.) Second, do you know if this is the intended behavior of the newer version of `memoir`.

Comment: @apc: I've changed the `\bibname` back to **References**. I am no real `memoir` user and I don't claim that I understand `memoir` really. I've no answer for your question about `intented behaviour`, unfortunately.

Comment: @apc `memoir` has not really changed any of this for a long time, `biblatex` just does things differently.

Comment: @daleif: One could say that `biblatex` is rather designed for `book.cls` etc.

Comment: I don't know. I'd rather say that it takes the same route as the caption package, it overwrites whatever is provided by the chosen class and provides its own instead. It is a sensible approach with pros and cons

Comment: @daleif: Yes, I did not intend to call it `non-sense` ;-) It's (La)TeX in the end, where (almost) everything can be redefined

Comment: BTW might be better to hook up the bibname change to babel?

Comment: @daleif: Yes, I will do later on...

Comment: Changing `\bibname` can be avoided by using `\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
\section*{#1}%
\markboth{#1}{#1}}` (we use `\refname` instead of `\bibname`). Come to think of it, just using `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]` would be even easier. BTW the original definition for `bibliography` with article memoir is `\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
    \chapter*{#1}%
    \ifmemoirbibintoc
      {\phantomsection
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
      {}%
    \markboth{\memUChead{#1}}{\memUChead{#1}}}` so you might want to start there.

Comment: If that's the original definition, then it's all the more puzzling that `memoir` 3.7c prints formats the references as a section heading in the first MWE.

Comment: @apc That is the current original definition, but please see my comment to your question for a history of that definition, it used to use `\section` instead of `\chapter`.